# Розділовий знак після другої репліки підряд

Tags: пунктуація, пряма-мова

Якщо персонаж говорить декілька реплік підряд, то за яким з цих двох варіантів треба розставляти знаки?

-- Привіт, - сказала Аліса. - Я якраз йшла сюди[.] - Продовжила вона.

-- Привіт, - сказала Аліса. - Я якраз йшла сюди[,] - продовжила вона.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Підручники розглядають діалог як підвид прямої мови. Тому зазвичай правила записуються для прямої мови (що у лапках) і автоматично розповсюджуються на діалоги також.

У підручниках [згадуються](https://webpen.com.ua/pages/Syntax_and_punctuation/direct_speech.html) лише прості варіанти речень з прямою мовою — тобто, лише такі, де є лише одна частина авторського тексту («П/п» — пряма мова; «а» — авторський текст):

- «П», — а.
- «П!» — а.
- «П?» — а.
- «П…» — а.
- «П, — а, — п».
- «П, — а. — П… (?,!)»
- «П… (?,!) — а. — П… (?,!)»
- «П… (?,!) — а, а: — П… (?,!)»

Зауважимо, що нас цікавить саме авторський текст наприкінці речення (а не усередині проміж частин прямої мови). Тобто, розглядаємо лише перші чотири вищенаведені приклади.

Незважаючи на відсутність складних варіантів, ми можемо вивести правило: крапка наприкінці прямої мови замінюється на кому; усі інші знаки (знак оклику, запитання, три крапки) залишаються як є.

Таким чином, я схиляюся до другого варіанту — коми і тире.
Якби це був вигук — було б знак оклику і тире.

---

Окреме зауваження: знак «мінус» (а також n-dash) не є замінником до тире (m-dash).